# Silverlight cross access/domain Issue

Tags: c#, silverlight

I just inherited a Silverlight application and am running into an issue. I'm getting a communicationexception/securityexception when the application starts up (when the service tries to feed the silverlight app the current user).

I can see in Fiddler that it's trying to find ClientAccessPolicy.xml and CrossDomain.xml, but both requests are returning HTTP400. I can also see the request is being made again localhost.:2981.

This application was built in Visual Studio 2010 and runs fine in the older visual studio web host. I'm trying to run this in 2013 under IIS Express, and I'm wondering if that is the issue I'm seeing here.

Any thoughts?

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost.:2981/service/Users.svc'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.
  StackTrace:
       at System.ServiceModel.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.ChannelBase`1.EndInvoke(String methodName, Object[] args, IAsyncResult result)
       at Art.Client.UI.Services.Users.UsersClient.UsersClientChannel.EndGetCurrentUser(IAsyncResult result)
       at Art.Client.UI.Services.Users.UsersClient.Art.Client.UI.Services.Users.IUsers.EndGetCurrentUser(IAsyncResult result)
       at Art.Client.UI.Services.Users.UsersClient.OnEndGetCurrentUser(IAsyncResult result)
       at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.OnAsyncCallCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
  InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
       Message=""
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
            at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
       InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
            Message=Security error.
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
                 at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b__9(Object sendState)
                 at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
            InnerException:
```

The ClientAccessPolicy.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="http://*"/>
        <domain uri="https://*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Comment: what port are you loading the app from? `localhost:80` and `localhost:2941` are two entirely separate systems as far as cross-domain is concerned.

Comment: The client UI is running on port 2201, the services are running on 2981.